# VHDL UCF - how to define a constraint that has no pin?

Tags: constraints, vhdl, fpga

I'm working with some simple VGA driver code for use with the Xilinx Spartan 6 FPGA (via a Papilio Pro board). The code expects to have 4-bits of output per color, and so defines logic vectors for each color. However, my setup doesn't happen to provide the full 4 bits per color so I wanted to find a creative way to control this via the UCF.

The original UCF defined 4 pins for each color. In the case of blue, I only have two pins, so I chose to map the two I have to blues MSBs, thus:

```
NET Blue(0)                 IOSTANDARD=LVTTL;  # N/C
NET Blue(1)                 IOSTANDARD=LVTTL;  # N/C
NET Blue(2)     LOC="P92" | IOSTANDARD=LVTTL;  # to a pin
NET Blue(3)     LOC="P87" | IOSTANDARD=LVTTL;  # to a pin
```

(I totally omitted the first two constraints at first, and it still compiled and worked but complained about the inconsistent voltage standards (the absent ones defaulted to IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25), thus throwing "WARNING:Place:838 - An IO Bus with more than one IO standard is found.")

The main warning is the one I'd like to know how to eliminate, preferably within the UCF:

```
WARNING:Place:837 - Partially locked IO Bus is found. 
    Following components of the bus are not locked: 
     Comp: Blue<1>
     Comp: Blue<0>
```

**What's the right way to map a net without a programmable pin location to a default value (logic '1' or '0', or perhaps a tri-state value) *within the UCF* in such a way as to eliminate this "Partially locked IO Bus" sort of warning?**

My goal is that, in a setup with more or fewer bits per channel being driven by pins, only the UCF should need to change (not the source code). What I did works, despite the warnings... I'd just like to do it better and properly eliminate these warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked for pins within the top level of your code (on your `entity`).  The tools therefore have to provide them.  Hence you have to map them (otherwise it'll pick some random ones for you, which you usually don't want)

If those pins really have nowhere to go on the board and never will have, then remove them from the design completely (UCF and HDL).

Otherwise, you have to LOC them.  You could add a `PULLDOWN` in the UCF to them to ensure they go to a low value.

Comment: If necessary, wrap the top level in a VHDL adapter that quietly drops the pins. This saves modifying the "top level" itself! Simply leaving the ports, without LOC constraints, will give you randomly placed pins which you DON'T want! Also, check the Map Report (.mrp) file to make sure what you are getting is correct.

Comment: [Upvote question if educational] Too bad you can't pull unlocated I/O up or down within the UCF (since it's the actual map between the device itself and the underlying VHDL it seemed like a logical place to tie up such loose ends). The map report doesn't have pin numbers, but the .pad report does show that the "UNLOCATED" pads are indeed routed randomly (strangely, with no clear warning/error). And trying to connect everything unused to one pad causes "Pack:2811 - Directed packing was unable to obey the user design". Just found another similar Q&A: fpgarelated.com/usenet/fpga/show/106417-1.php

Comment: @Martin - And thanks for the answer. Now to figure out the best way to create a wrapper (if it's more than just another module that acts as an interface). The following is where I later read about the lack of a clear warning/error for this - turns out you were on that thread too! http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/option-to-fail-xilinx-process-if-pins-are-unconstrained

Comment: The wrapper IS just a module (ent/arch) implementing the desired interface (ports) and instantiating the actual "top level" module. Most of the connections are in the latter's port map. The only other code in it is to adapt any modified ports (delete a few output pins, connect unused inputs to 0V etc) A few minutes work.

Comment: @Brian - It sounds pretty simple, I just wasn't sure if it was a special type of module with a special syntax or just an interface-type layer. Thanks for the helpful suggestion!

Comment: It's turning out to be tricky... I've created an interface with an intermediate 4-bit signal that I'm port mapping to the 4-bit internal signal, and I'm directly assigning the top two bits of it to the 2-bit final output signal (ignoring the other two intermediate bits). It builds and works but I get "Node <foo> of sequential type is unconnected in block <bar>" warnings for those unused intermediate bits (though at least I'm NOT getting the extra randomly-assigned output pins now!) The warnings appear benign but I want to understand them and hopefully eliminate them neatly if possible.

Comment: I've seen this warning when synthesizing and implementing a module onto the test board. The program then gave weird output with the on-board resources (switches, LEDs, etc.). When I added a wrapper to drop the unused I/O pins, all errors went away.